# Notation in One-dimensional Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy, notation

I am reading a book where it write the one-dimensional stationary Schrodinger equation as
$$
[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dζ^2}-Γ{\rm sech}^2(bζ)]ψ(ζ)=Eψ(ζ).
$$
It is known that the equation is usually written as
$$
[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)]ψ(x)=Eψ(x).
$$
I speculate that the author may have $bζ$ instead of $x$. But I am confused with the component of potential energy $-Γ{\rm sech}^2(bζ)$. My guess is that we may have $2mΓb^2(2π)^2/h^2 $ instead of the $V$. Isn't it?

Comment: Well, teh name of the variable is arbitrary, so there's nothing wrong with the potential energy being that function entirely.

Comment: This form of potential energy in the 1D Schrodinger equation is a famous one. See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30807/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246843/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B6schl%E2%80%93Teller_potential (and references therein).

Comment: @LonelyProf It probably wouldn't be hard to expand that into an answer

Answer (score 3):

On prompting from a moderator, I'm offering my comment as an answer!

It seems most likely that the potential energy function given in your equation was a deliberate choice, as it is a famous potential: the [Pöschl-Teller potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B6schl%E2%80%93Teller_potential). It can be solved exactly, giving a finite number of bound states. Also, for suitable values of the strength parameter $\Gamma$, it is [reflectionless](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/246843/reflectionless-potentials-in-quantum-mechanics), meaning that incident waves transmit perfectly through it.

The value of $b$ establishes a length scale for the potential, and your speculation about the combination of $\Gamma$ and factors of $\hbar^2/2m$ 
(where $\hbar=h/2\pi$) probably relates to making a convenient choice of energy scale so as to reduce the equation to a dimensionless form (see the pages I referenced, as well as [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30807/bound-states-for-sech-squared-potential)).